# How to update a Task Group using the REST API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Let's say I am trying to update a task groups description.

1. I get all task groups with a get request
   `GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/distributedtask/taskgroups?api-version=6.0-preview.1`
2. I filter it by name and get the id. E.g. `aaabbbcc-abcd-ae12-917d-97f1935b1542`
3. After I got the ID, I make a PUT request using
   `PUT https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/distributedtask/taskgroups/aaabbbcc-abcd-ae12-917d-97f1935b1542?api-version=6.0-preview.1`
   with a JSON body like

   ```
   {
   "description": "this is the new description",
   "id": "aaabbbcc-abcd-ae12-917d-97f1935b1542"
   }
   ```

But the last step is not working. I would get the following error:

```
{
    "$id": "1",
    "innerException": null,
    "message": "Task group aaabbbcc-abcd-ae12-917d-97f1935b1542 not found.",
    "typeName": "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.WebApi.MetaTaskDefinitionNotFoundException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.WebApi",
    "typeKey": "MetaTaskDefinitionNotFoundException",
    "errorCode": 0,
    "eventId": 3000
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do it is to use the Task Group you got in the `GET` API and change the description there, then convert it to JSON and send all the object in the `PUT` API.

For example - in PowerShell:

```
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,"YOUR-PAT")))
$headers = @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}

$url = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/distributedtask/taskgroups?api-version=6.0-preview.1"

$taskGroups= Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $url -Headers $headers -ContentType 'application/json'

$taskGroups.value[0].description = "test"

$json = $taskGroups.value[0] | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Put -Uri $url -Headers $headers -ContentType 'application/json' -Body $json
```

Comment: Thank you. You need to actually send all of the fields mentioned in the documentation [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/taskgroups/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#request-body).

I just got sidetracked by the `TaskGroupUpdateParameter` TypeScript definition, which marks all the fields as optional.

Also, you have to increment the revision number after each update.